# Image sort with matlab

Tags: image, matlab, sorting, matlab-cvst

I am trying to do some kind of image sorting.

I have 5 images and first one is my main image. I am trying to sort images according to their similarity.(Most similar image to less similar image).

Matlab had `matchfeature` method but I dont think I jave used it correctly because my results are wrong.I try to use:

```
[indexPairs,matchmetric] = matchFeatures(features1,features2,"MatchThreshold,10")
```

then i try to sort the `matchmetric` array.But it didnt work

Can anyone tell me some algorithm or any tips ?Thank you..

Comment: `matchFeatures` only works when you invoke one of MATLAB's feature detection algorithms: `MSER`, `SURF`, etc.  You can't use images as direct input into `matchFeatures`.  In addition, the inputs are **feature matrices**.  See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html and check out their examples on how to use this properly.  However, you want to find image similarity, not interest point similarity.  The suggestion by @Benoit_11 may work.

Comment: BTW, if you are doing what I think you're doing, this is an **image retrieval** problem.  Google search: Content-Based Image Retrieval.  You are trying to search for images that are similar to a query image. There are many methods to solve this, and this is still an unsolved problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the correlation coefficient between every images and your main image and then sort them based on the coefficient.

```
doc corr2
```

For example, let's say you store all your images in a cell array (called ImageCellArray) in which the first image is your "main image":

```
for i = 2:size(ImageCellArray,2) % size(ImageCellArray,2) is the total # of images, i.e. the size of the cell array containing them.

CorrCoeff(i) = corr2(rgb2gray(ImageCellArray{1}),rgb2gray(ImageCellArray{i}));

end

[values indices] = sort(CorrCoeff); % sort the coefficients and get the number of the corresponging image.
```

Then you're good to go I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the PSNR (peak signal-to-noise ratio) for each image compared to the main image. PSNR is a metric commonly used to measure the quality of a reconstructed compression against the original image.

It's [implemented in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/psnr.html) in the Computer Vision System toolbox as a functional block, and there is also a `psnr` [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psnr.html) in the Image Processing toolbox. The result will be a number in decibels you could use to rank the images. A higher PSNR value indicates greater similarity.

Comment: One small caveat with this method.  Supposing you had an image of entirely gray and you wanted to compare with an image that was entirely white. One could argue that this image holds a lot of similarity.  It is simply the gray image but has its intensities shifted by 128.  However, the PSNR would report this as having a very low value when subjectively they should be similar.  I haven't tried this to verify, but this is what I believe would happen.

Comment: True; the usefulness of PSNR (or any other metric) depends on what the OP means by similarity. If these images are supposed to be minimally altered representations of the same image, PSNR should be a good choice. If higher level features such as homogeneity or subject matter are of interest, then it probably isn't.  
Also, normalizing the pixel values would take care of the particular issue you raised, if something like a uniform offset is considered a trivial difference.

Comment: Definitely agree with you there!  We don't know what types of images they are - if they are slightly altered versions of the image, or if they are radically different.  If they are radically different, then this is an image retrieval problem and that is still an unsolved problem to this day.  If there are slightly altered versions, PSNR should work fine.  Normalizing should help too - perhaps standardizing each intensity by subtracting its mean and dividing by the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example of [image retrieval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-search-using-point-features.html). Instead of matching the features between pairs of images it uses the `KDTreeSearcher` from the Statistics Toolbox to find nearest neighbors of each feature from the query image across the whole set of database images.